# Is it possible to hide or pack the *.qss file when using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have created a Qt project using VS2010, and used the qss file to modify the UI. In order to set up each widget different styles,  I put many of my class names into the qss file to distinguish the widgets, such as MyPicWidget. The question is that I have to pack the qss file in to my installer, and with out it, the UI can't show the effect. But I don't want the user to get my class names. Is there any way to hide or pack in or "encrypt" the qss file, without losing its effect?

Comment: Save this file in Qt resource system? In this case this file will be embedded in exe file.

Comment: Excellent idea!I forgot that you can almost pack everything in the qrc file, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Qt resource file, and everything is working well. Thanks to **Chernobyl**.